# How to refer a table inside a table in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am posting this because Google didn't show me any guide or reference on this and I wasted more than an hour searching for a solution.

I have a table fetched from a database. I added a column through 'Invoke Custom Function'. This function returns a table type. I want to see the columns of this table type data directly in the parent table.

[image: Table type returned by function]
Table type returned by function

[image]

The columns in the nested table.
I want the columns in the nested table to be shown directly on the parent table.

Comment: Does clicking the expand icon in the top right of your table not give you what you want?

Comment: It does but, as stated, I wanted to get the columns in the parent table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solves the problem.

```
Table.ExpandTableColumn(table as table, column as text, columnNames as list, optional newColumnNames as nullable list) as table
```

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/m/table-expandtablecolumn)